# Why did Heimdall alert Odin and authorities about Thor’s escape?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-marvel, thor-the-dark-world

In *Thor: The Dark World*, Thor committed treason against Odin and Asgardian law by taking Jane (and Loki) outside Asgard. Before they escaped using Loki's secret inter-realm passage, the Asgardian army was chasing them.

Heimdall told Odin about Thor’s treason, and that was part of the plan. Why? Why couldn't Thor escape silently (and Heimdall reveal his treason after the escape)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don’t think the Einherjar were chasing Thor **because** Heimdall told them. I think they found out another way.

As Heimdall tells Odin that he has committed treason, Tyr arrives at the Observatory to tell Odin that “The Mortal has been taken”. If he was relying on Heimdall alone, there’s no way he could know this. It’s more likely somebody would notice the knocked-out soldiers in Jane’s cell, or the fact that the soldier sent to give her food never returned.

Instead, I thought this was a bending of the rules for Heimdall’s vows: he has to inform Odin of treason, and presumably in some sort of timely manner. This also gets Odin and his personal guards away from the Palace, and too far away to intervene with the rescue attempt.